# Zend Framework PDF generation unicode issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, unicode, utf-8

I have troubles using Zend Framework's PDF

When I create PDF file I need to use UTF-8 as encoding. 
This is the code I am using to generate simple pdf file.
I always get this wrong displayed.
Instead of seeing 'Faktúra' in pdf file, it gives me 'Faktú'
Instead of seeing 'Dodávateľ:' in pdf file, it gives me 'Dodáva'

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();    
$pdf->pages[] = ($page1 = $pdf->newPage('A4'));    
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF');    
$page1->setFont($font, 20);    
$page1->drawText('Faktúra', 40, 803, 'UTF-8');    
$page1->drawText('Dodaváteľ:', $width_left, $height, 'UTF-8');
```

So I tried to load font from Windows directory

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF');
```

But it gives me the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message
>   'Insufficient data to read 2 bytes'

It is really driving me crazy and I believe some of you would have little hints for me:)
Solving the error would be the best solution...

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you save the php source file as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, the source is as UTF-8
I was wandering maybe the PDF file itself should also itself be saved as UTF-8, but Zend Framework does not support this kind of saving.

I am saving the pdf file this way

$pdf->save('faktury/'.$invoice.'.pdf');

Comment: I don't think you need to save the pdf as UTF-8 .. pdf is a binary format - I'm pretty sure it handles that stuff internally. Maybe you need to have the iconv extension installed and enabled (Just a wild guess)

Comment: iconv has been correctly installed... I don't know where to look for solution further.. any clues?

Comment: Which version are you using? Try getting the latest from svn/trunk. Apparently they made some changes recently: http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-5121

Answer (score 1):

try using **utf8_decode()**

For example:

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();    
$pdf->pages[] = ($page1 = $pdf->newPage('A4'));    
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF');    
$page1->setFont($font, 20);    
$page1->drawText(utf8_decode('Faktúra'), 40, 803, 'UTF-8');    
$page1->drawText(utf8_decode('Dodaváteľ:'), $width_left, $height, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend pdf functionality is not yet very sophisticated. on http://www.starmind.com we use [tcpdf](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) which is based on fpdf. both are free to use.